# Sorting SQL records

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I need to sort my SQL stored procedure recordset (shown below) alphabetically (by CustomerName), but also maintaining the sequential order of RecordID (meaning RecordID 2 is above RecordID 3, in relation to ParentID & ID fields).  Any suggestions?

```
ID           ParentID         RecordID        CustomerName
53445347        5344        2                 Witt - 47
534453475345    53445347    3                 Witt - 45
534453475346    53445347    3                 Witt - 46
53445351        5344        2                 Sjob - 51
534453515348    53445351    3                 Sjob - 48
534453515349    53445351    3                 Sjob - 49
534453515350    53445351    3                 Sjob - 50
53445357        5344        2                 Hal - 57
534453575355    53445357    3                 Hal - 55
534453575356    53445357    3                 Hal - 56
534453577252    53445357    3                 Hal - 52
53446852        5344        2                 Boston, - 52
534468526850    53446852    3                 Boston, - 50
534468526851    53446852    3                 Boston, - 51
534468527205    53446852    3                 Boston, - 05
53447884        5344        2                 Agri - 84
534478847883    53447884    3                 Agri - 83
534478847957    53447884    3                 Agri - 57
```

The intended output would be like:

```
53447884        5344        2                 Agri - 84
534478847883    53447884    3                 Agri - 83
534478847957    53447884    3                 Agri - 57
53446852        5344        2                 Boston, - 52
534468526850    53446852    3                 Boston, - 50
534468526851    53446852    3                 Boston, - 51
534468527205    53446852    3                 Boston, - 05
53445357        5344        2                 Hal - 57
534453575355    53445357    3                 Hal - 55
534453575356    53445357    3                 Hal - 56
534453577252    53445357    3                 Hal - 52
53445351        5344        2                 Sjob - 51
534453515348    53445351    3                 Sjob - 48
534453515349    53445351    3                 Sjob - 49
534453515350    53445351    3                 Sjob - 50
53445347        5344        2                 Witt - 47
534453475345    53445347    3                 Witt - 45
534453475346    53445347    3                 Witt - 46
```

Comment: not sure to understand, could you show a sample of wanted result ?

Comment: <<< What have you tried!? >>>

Comment: Also, if you've got nicely formatted sample input, try making some nicely formatted sample output.

Comment: ORDER BY CustomerName, RecordID?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I updated my original post. Hope that helps you.

Comment: @RobHarrop ORDER BY CustomerName, RecordID would display all the RecordID = 2 and then all the RecordID = 3... not what I am looking for.

Comment: @DotNetRookie surely that would be ORDER BY RecordID, CustomerName. The issue with my suggestion seems to be that you have some IDs or some such embedded in your customer names. The approach suggested by Raphael Althaus gets around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if all your Customer names are formed as in your sample :

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING( CustomerName, 0, CHARINDEX( '-', CustomerName)), RecordID
```

By the way, if you have any chance to change your model, split the alpha and the numeric part of CustomerName in two fields, and your life will be better, and the world will be as one.

If you can have customer names without the `-`

Rather try

```
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', CustomerName) = 0 
               THEN CustomerName
               ELSE SUBSTRING( CustomerName, 0, CHARINDEX( '-', CustomerName))
            END,
            RecordID
```

Comment: This looks good.... this might be the answer... need to test it out. Thanks @Raphaël Althaus

Comment: I agree @Raphaël Althaus, but this is only a sample recordset... other values in that column ... some are all alpha and some are all numeric.... so if I do that... the world will come to a stop :(

Comment: @DotNetRookie well maybe look at the second solution if not all of your CustomerNames have a '-'